# When an instance of a class is returned, do all properties get returned?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

Let's say I have a class called `Customer` with some properties:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustAddr = GetCustAddr(); //Long procedure returning address

    public double CustAcct = GetCustAcct(); //Long procedure returning account

    public string CustInvoice = GetCustInvoice(); //Long procedure returning invoice
}
```

This class is returned via a function:

```
public Customer GetData(string query)
{
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    //set the values for each of the properties
    return cust;
}
```

Right now it is returning the whole class and I can use it like this:

```
lblDisplay = GetData("QUERY").CustAddr.ToString();
```

However, suppose each property takes a lot of time to compute. If I only want the CustAddr value, it still computes and has `CustAcct` and `CustInvoice` available for me.

How do I alter my function to **only** return the property I'm looking for, aside from breaking up my class into individual procedures to call? For example, I could just:

```
lblDisplay = GetCustAddr().ToString();
```

but that's not what I'm looking for. I think it's better to have all my data in an organized structure instead of a bunch of different procedures.

Comment: Those are fields not properties ;)

Comment: I suggest reading [What is the difference between a Field and a Property in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c).

Comment: Use Lazy initialization or proxy pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great candidate for lazy initialization.  Here I present an example using properties (you have fields).

```
public class Customer
{
    public Lazy<string> CustAddr { get; private set; }
    public Lazy<double> CustAcct { get; private set; }
    public Lazy<string> CustInvoice { get; private set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        CustAddr = new Lazy<string>(GetCustAddr);
        CustAcct = new Lazy<double>(GetCustAcct);
        CustInvoice = new Lazy<string>(GetCustInvoice);
    }
}
```

However, I would be remiss if I didn't point out that you should not use floating-point types (`float`, `double`) to store monetary values.  Consider instead using `decimal`.

Comment: You point out using `double` instead of `decimal` but you don't bring up the fact that he is exposing public fields not properties?

Comment: That said, it's not clear why OP doesn't store the object in a variable and access each property  one at a time instead of always creating it via `GetData`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am editing to use properties as well. But if I had to pick one of those two to fix, I would indeed pick usage of floating-point types.  Properties begets easier maintenance; fixed-point for monetary data begets *not making bad calculations*.

Comment: One might want to hide the `Lazy<T>` from the consumer and just expose the wrapped object via a property. Otherwise, you're leaking implementation details.

Comment: @NicholasCarey I thought about doing that as well, but decided against it at least for this particular example.  I have heard arguments for and against doing that, so I will let OP choose which approach makes the most sense for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Why use an exotic solution when there's a vanilla one?

Implementing the calculation on the `get` of the properties.

*NB: What you have are public fields, not properties*

Very simple solution (nothing exotic!)

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ctOX6)

e.g.

```
public class Customer
{
    private double ? _custAcct = null;
    public double CustAcct
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_custAcct.HasValue)
            {
                _custAcct = GetCustAcct();
            }

            return _custAcct.Value;
        }
    }

    private double GetCustAcct()
    {
        // do something that takes a long time
        return 1234.45;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is *lazy loading* or *lazy initialization*. You write your properties something like this:

```
public class MyLazyWidget
{
  . . .
  public BigExpensiveObject MyLazyProperty
  {
    get
    {
      if ( BigExpensiveObjectBackingStore == null )
      {
        BigExpensiveObjectBackingStore = ExpensiveOperation() ;
      }
        return BigExpensiveObjectBackingStore ;
    }
  }
  private static BigExpensiveObjectBackingStore = null ;
  . . .
}
```

And if your app is multi-threaded, you'll need to worry about race conditions, so you need to synchronize access to the static backing store:

```
public class MyLazyWidget
{
  . . .
  public BigExpensiveObject MyLazyProperty
  {
    get
    {
      lock( MyLazyPropertyLatch )
      {
        if ( BigExpensiveObjectBackingStore == null )
        {
          BigExpensiveObjectBackingStore = ExpensiveOperation() ;
        }
      }
      return BigExpensiveObjectBackingStore ;
    }
  }
  private static readonly object MyLazyPropertyLatch = new object() ;
  private static BigExpensiveObjectBackingStore = null ;
  . . .
}
```

Comment: Note that `Lazy<T>` takes care of the latch for you.

Comment: Yes...but not everybody is using .Net 4.x. `Lazy<T>` is a little more concise as well.